# Read Data from a serial port and write to influxdb

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have a energy meter which sends the kWh count periodically every few seconds via a serial port.
To store this data I write the counter value and the calculated average power of the last 10s in a influxdb measurment.

To calculate the power i use a loop that compares the current counter value with the one 10s ago. To avoid that the loop is interrupted by reading the serial interface or sending the data via http i use serial_asyncio and aiohttp.

I am pretty new to Python and got my script running by doing serveral asyncio tutorials, so i am not sure if i mixed some old and new syntax.

The script is working, but I am not happy with a few things.

1. Is there a better way to pass the counter value from the serial data_received function to my calc_delta function without the use of global?
2. Am I using asyncio properly? I found different examples using asyncio.ensure_future() or loop.run_until_complete().
3. Is the overall structure okay, what could i have done better?

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
import serial_asyncio
import serial
import time


value = None
last_value = 0
token = "myInfluxdbToken"


class Input(asyncio.Protocol):
    data_buffer = ""

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        print("port opened", transport)

    def data_received(self, data):
        global value

        self.data_buffer += data.decode("utf-8")
        # find counter value in received string
        if "eHZ" in self.data_buffer:
            data_tmp = self.data_buffer.replace("\r\n", "")
            value_str = data_tmp.partition("1.8.1*255(")[2][:11]

            if len(value_str) == 11:
                value = float(value_str)
                print(str(value))
                asyncio.ensure_future(send_data(value, "counter"))
            # Reset the data_buffer!
            self.data_buffer = ""


async def calc_delta():
    global value, last_value
    # calculate counter delta
    while True:
        delta = 0
        print(value)
        if value:
            delta = value - last_value
            last_value = value
        # 10s * 3600s/h * 1000W  Calculates Avg Power of last 10s from kWh delta
        deltaW = delta / 10 * 3600 * 1000
        if deltaW < 50000:
            await send_data(deltaW, "deltaW")
            print(time.perf_counter(), deltaW)
        else:
            print(time.perf_counter(), "data invalid")

        await asyncio.sleep(10)


async def send_data(data, tag):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(
            "http://localhost:8086/api/v2/write?org=my_org&bucket=testdata&precision=s",
            data=f"ehzdata,type={tag} value={data}",
            headers={"Authorization": f"Token {token}"},
        ) as response:
            print("Status:", response.status)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
serial_coro = serial_asyncio.create_serial_connection(
    loop, Input, "/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, bytesize=7
)
counter_coro = calc_delta()
asyncio.ensure_future(serial_coro)
loop.run_until_complete(counter_coro)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```